# How to know that which button is clicked, if buttons are added dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to solve that problem, If anyone knows how to solve that then please let me know. If required, then I will send the code personally to figure out the mistakes.

There are two containers: left and right. In Left, there is a from where I take values of title, description and status(active/inactive) from text boxes and radio buttons(active/inactive). Then after pressing submit button all values are filled in table of right-container with edit and delete button attached after clicking submit button every time. I want to delete specific row where delete button is clicked. But I don't know how to access that button while onclick function(doDelete()) is same in all the buttons.

```
function fillData() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var counter = table.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
  var key = counter;
  var row = table.insertRow(counter);
  row.id = "row-" + key;

  var titleCell = row.insertCell(0);
  var descCell = row.insertCell(1);
  var statusCell = row.insertCell(2);
  var actionCell = row.insertCell(3);

  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";
  editButton.id = "edit-" + key;
  editButton.setAttribute("onclick", "doEdit()");

  var delButton = document.createElement("button");
  delButton.innerText = "Delete";
  delButton.id = "delete-" + key;
  delButton.setAttribute("onclick", "doDelete()");

  titleCell.innerHTML = document.getElementById("panel-title").value;
  descCell.innerHTML = document.getElementById("panel-description").value;
  statusCell.innerHTML = (function () {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("status");
    for (i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
        return radios[i].value;
      }
    }
  }());

  actionCell.appendChild(editButton);
  actionCell.appendChild(delButton);

  var delBtnArr = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
  console.log(delBtnArr);
}
```

Actual Results: After pressing delete button, the whole rows are deleted.
Expected Results: After pressing delete button, the specific row is deleted where button is clicked.

Comment: Pass to your delete and edit method `this.id`. In your specific function iterate through the dom tree to reach the sutiable table row.

Comment: Please show the code, where you delete the row.

Comment: actually I am getting confused about how to access that element so there is no code written in doDelete() function

Comment: Please give me your email-id so I can share my code with you

Answer (score 0):

Javascript also sends the assosiated event as parameter and in this way you can get id by using event utilities. You can get the clicked button id as below. By getting that id I think you can also get the associated row. After that you can delete the row.

```
doDelete(event){
 let clickedButtonId = e.target.id;
 //get row id. I think you can get it.
 document.removeElement(rowId);
}
```

Comment: ok I will try it. If problem occur again then I will contact you

Comment: @Champ did you try?

Answer (score 0):

## [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

### Bind/Register the Ancestor to Event

Dynamically added tags cannot bind to an event handler/listener, only tags that have existed since the page was loaded can. So for multiple dynamically added tags such as the buttons you have to find an ancestor tag that they all share incommon and bind it to whatever event you need to listen for. For your buttons it can be the closest ancestor `table`* (recommended) to the furthest `window`:

> ```
> // On-event property. ALWAYS PASS THE EVENT OBJECT 
> table.onclick = function(event) {...
> ```

***OR***

> ```
> // Event Listener. Abbreviating the [Event Object][2] is OK, but you must be consistent.
> table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {...
> ```

#### **Do not use on-event attributes** <del>`<button onclick="func()"...`</del>

<sup><sup>✱</sup>Technically the closest ancestor is `tbody` even if you didn't add it to the table, the browser will add it by default.</sup>

---

### Use [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) Properties

Remember to pass the Event Object because you'll need it to...

- ...find out which button you actually clicked with `event.target` property.
- ...get a reference to the table with `event.currentTarget` property.
- ...possibly prevent default behavior such as stopping a form from submitting to a server with [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method.

Review the demo, it will have specific details on the event handlers.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
var table = document.querySelector("table");

document.forms[0].onsubmit = fillData;

/*
This onevent property handler has two functions note it is bound 
to the table NOT the buttons.
There's two conditionals and they only focus on classNames of 
either .del or .edit. Once it's determined if the clicked tag has
one of these classes then the appropriate function is called.
If neither class was clicked there's no opportunity for anything
else to act on the click because both conditionals end with 
return false thereby terminating the event handler.
*/
table.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'del') {
    delRow(e);
    return false;
  }
  if (e.target.className === 'edit') {
    editRow(e);
    return false;
  }
};

function fillData(e) {
  var ui = e.target.elements;
  e.preventDefault();
  var idx = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow();
  row.id = 'r-' + idx;

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var data1 = ui.title.value;
  cell1.textContent = data1;

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var data2 = ui.desc.value;
  cell2.textContent = data2;

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var data3 = ui.chk.checked ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
  cell3.textContent = data3;

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var btns = `
  <button class='edit'>&#128221;</button>
  <button class='del'>&#10060;</button>`;
  cell4.innerHTML = btns;
}

/*
Reference the .closest() row from clicked button
Get that row's id and split() it at the dash and pop() the number.
Then get a reference to the bound ancestor (table) and deleteRow() with the new number you just got.
*/
function delRow(e) {
  var row = e.target.closest('tr');
  var idx = row.id.split('-').pop();
  e.currentTarget.deleteRow(idx);
}

/*
Same as before get the index number from the closest row's id.
Reference the table and use the .rows property and number.
This reference will now allow you to use the .cells property.
Use the .cells property to toggle the contenteditable attribute
on the first three cells.
*/
function editRow(e) {
  var row = e.target.closest('tr');
  var idx = row.id.split('-').pop();
  var R = e.currentTarget.rows[idx];
  for (let c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    var cell = R.cells[c];
    if (cell.hasAttribute('contenteditable')) {
      cell.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
    } else {
      cell.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 16px/25px Consolas;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

fieldset {
  width: fit-content
}

input,
label,
textarea {
  font: inherit
}

input,
label,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
}

#title {
  width: 27.5ch;
}

#chk {
  display: none;
}

#chk+label::after {
  content: '\2610';
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#chk:checked+label::after {
  content: '\2611';
}

[type='reset'] {
  margin-left: 5%
}

td {
  min-width: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 25px;
}

tr td:last-child {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

button {
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form id='data'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Data</legend>
    <input id='title' type='text' placeholder='Title'><br>
    <textarea id='desc' rows='3' cols='25' placeholder='Description'></textarea><br>
    <input id='chk' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='chk'>Active </label>
    <input type='reset'>
    <input type='submit'>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<hr>

<table></table>
```